# Modulus not returning the correct value for a non-negative input

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, modulus

I am working on a scaled down `RSA encryption` and `decryption` methods and everything seems to be working well, until I try to take the modulus of a number. The modulus operator isn't returning the expected result.

```
        for(int k = 0; k < sA.length; k++){
            int value = Integer.parseInt(sA[k]);
            System.out.println("value : " + value);
            double mToE = Math.pow(value,e);
            System.out.println("mToE: " + mToE);
            double c = mToE % n;
            System.out.println("C: " + c);
```

`sA` is an array containing the values `{06707708, 30670320, 50050050}`.

`mToE` represents M(in this case each string in sA) raised to the power of `e(13)`.

`C = M^e mod n` where n is input as a parameter.

These specific lines output:

```
value : 6707708
mToE: 5.56498415666044E88
C: 5.2630797E7
0
value : 30670320
mToE: 2.1248975415575414E97
C: 8.973537E7
1
value : 50050050
mToE: 1.2366838911816623E100
C: 3.4150233E7
2
```

For example the first value of c should be:

```
c: 3.2059734E7
```

or `32059734`

What reason could there be for getting this result?

Thanks in advance for all of your advice.

Comment: What is your `n` in the given example? My suggestion is that the `double mToE` is causing the problem since you need to sacrifice precision in order to represent such large numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The `double` type has lots of precision, 53 bits, but that's not enough to store values as precise as unity at the very high values you're seeing.  The values of `mToE` are the `double` values that are closest to the true values of calculation.

With [the `Math.ulp` method (unit in last place)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-double-), we can determine the precision of a `double` value of the magnitude `5.56498415666044E88`.

```
System.out.println(Math.ulp(mToE));
```

This outputs

```
7.067388259113537E72
```

Because of this, your value is very likely to be off in 72 digits.  This will of course completely mess up the value of `c`, which is taken from a mod `%` operation.

For the necessary precision, you will need to use `BigInteger`s.  Also, `BigInteger` has its own [`modPow` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-) built specifically for your purpose.